# How do I remove an admin user from a CouchDB database?

Tags: couchdb, admin

I know I can use the command:

> curl -X PUT
>   http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/_config/admins/admin
>   -d '"password"'

to add a new admin to the server. How do I go about removing an admin user?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to DELETE the user `admin` that you setup with:

```
curl -X DELETE http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/_config/admins/admin
```

Note this is a bad example as you're deleting the user that you're authenticating as. The last part of the URL `admin` is the name of the user.

Comment: You could just change your URL to something like `http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/_config/admins/admin_to_remove` and then you wouldn't need your note.

Comment: if that doesn't work(like in my case) you can go to the UI and remove it from there: 127:0.0.1:5984/_utils . Then log in from the bottom-right and go to "Configuration" and remove the admin(s).

Comment: CouchDB is on 2.3 now (2019), so this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: It's still possible via Fauxton -> `_config` though

Comment: In Fauxton with CouchDb v 3.2.1 the configuration tab in the admins section, admins can be deleted.